# Using utilities how can I format a GPT disk without an EFI

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I have 8 disks in a RAID. They are 4TB each so can not be formatted with MBR or APM. The EFI takes up 200MB on each of the 8 disks so 1600 MB for no purpose is wasted.

I have tried using `diskutil` commands and been unsuccessful in reclaiming that space.

`sudo gpt show disk5`

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  7813365344      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  7813774984      262151         
  7814037135          32         Sec GPT table
  7814037167           1         Sec GPT header
```

I asked diskutil to create just one partition and it disregarded and added two anyway!

`diskutil partitionDisk disk5 1 GPT JHFS+  disk5 0`

```
Started partitioning on disk5
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk5s2 as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with name disk5
Initialized /dev/rdisk5s2 as a 4 TB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume with a 311296k journal
Mounting disk
Finished partitioning on disk5
/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk5
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk5s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS disk5                   4.0 TB     disk5s2
```

I know I can erase the EFI, but I also want to reclaim that space for the single partition. Thanks.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2166/_index.html

Apple's policy from 2006 is hopelessly outdated. An EFI is mandatory on a "big" disk, and a big disk is anything larger than 2 GB... yes.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `gpt` (or [`gdisk`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/)) to partition and `newfs_hfs` to format? I tried this on a 4 TB sparse disk image and was able to mount the file system.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have no experience with `newfs_hfs`. A quick glance at the man page is discouraging... looks very low level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EFI partition uses `409600/7814037168*100%=0.00524%` of the drive, while the JHFS+ partition uses `7813365344/7814037168*100%=99.99140%` of the drive. IMO, avoiding having an EFI partition is not worth the effort. Anyway, below is an answer.

---

This answer relies on using a command that can edit GUID Partition Tables (GPT), such as `gpt`, `gdisk` or `sgdisk`. Some pertinent information is given below.

- The `gpt` command is part of macOS. The `gdisk` and `sgdisk` commands are third party and are [currently maintained by Rod Smith](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/).
- The `gpt add` command is no longer available under certain versions of macOS, such as Ventura.
- The macOS operating system includes a MBR Partition Table editor command called `fdisk`. The `gdisk` command is a GPT version of the `fdisk` command. Like `fdisk`, `gdisk` is interactive. The `sgdisk` command is the non-interactive version of the `gdisk` command. The `gdisk` command has more functionality than the `sgdisk` command.
- The `gdisk` and `sgdisk` binaries can be downloaded from this [gptfdisk SourceForge website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/). The `gdisk` command was tested to work with newer versions of macOS on Intel Macs. Testing has shown this downloaded `sgdisk` command does not work on Intel Macs.  I do not know if either command, downloaded from this website, will work on Apple Silicon Macs.
- There is a [Homebrew formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gptfdisk) for `gptfdisk`. This is supposed to install both `gdisk` and `sgdisk` for the newest versions of macOS on both Intel and Apple Silicon Macs. Testing shows both commands work on Intel Macs. I did not test on Apple Silicon Macs.
- There are Linux man pages for [gdisk](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html) and [sgdisk](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/sgdisk.html).

---

***Note:** The OP's question used the volume name* `disk5`*. This answer will use the volume name* `mydisk5` *instead.*

### Drive without an EFI Partition

1. Create a new GPT with no entries.

   ```
   diskutil erasedisk free none gpt disk5
   diskutil erasevolume free none disk5s1
   ```
2. Add a partition of type `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` to the GPT. The value 7813774944 is the sum of the values 409600 and 7813365344. Below are three methods of add this partition. Choose only one of the three methods presented.

   - Use the `gpt` command, as shown below.

     ```
     sudo gpt add -b 40 -s 7813774944 -t hfs disk5
     ```
   - Use the interactive `gdisk` command, as shown below.

     ```
     sudo gdisk /dev/disk5
     ```

     The inputs to the `gdisk` command are given in the first column below.

     | Entry | Type | Comment |
     | --- | --- | --- |
     | `x` | Command | Goto experts menu. |
     | `l` | Command | Set the sector alignment value. |
     | `8` | Parameter | Enter an alignment on 8 sector boundaries. |
     | `m` | Command | Return to main menu. |
     | `n` | Command | Add a new partition. |
     | `1` | Parameter | Partition number. |
     | `40` | Parameter | First Sector. |
     | `+7813774944` | Parameter | Size in sectors. |
     | `af00` | Parameter | Code for `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` |
     | `w` | Command | Write table to disk and exit. |
     | `y` | Parameter | Confirm to proceed. |
   - Use the `sgdisk` command, as shown below.

     ```
     sudo sgdisk -a 8 -n 0:40:+7813774944 -t 0:af00 /dev/disk5
     ```
3. Format the partition and mount the volume.

   ```
   sudo newfs_hfs -J -v mydisk5 disk5s1
   diskutil mount disk5s1
   ```

---

### Drive without a Partition Table

Actually, you can format a drive without any partitioning scheme. For example, the commands below would do this.

```
diskutil erasedisk free none gpt disk5
sudo newfs_hfs -J -v mydisk5 disk5
diskutil mount disk5
```